# Advantages or disadvantages of using recycler view over the grid view

Tags: android

I have used grid view in my application, and reading some articles and watching some videos, it is recommended to use recycler view. What is the main advantages or disadvantages of using recyclerview over the grid view?

Comment: Advantage: recyclerview is stable and it works

Answer (score 2):

i think it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31199952/2290548). Only the reference is to a Listview. But almost the same set of advantages / disadvantages goes for Gridview as well.

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` is a more flexible and advanced version of `ListView`

The RecyclerView class simplifies the display and handling of large
data sets by providing:

- Layout managers for positioning items
- Default animations for common
  item operations, such as removal or addition of items

And there are many more advantages specially if you are dealing with huge data sets consuming considerable amount of memory several background operations.

For examples you will find most updated versions of messenger apps and google apps use `RecyclerView`. Check this official documentation.

[Creating Lists and Cards](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)